# How can I create a template that will auto populate/calculate cells based on a SKU value?

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet, autofill, sku

Every day I work with product data, both product creation and listing creation for the web, eBay, and Amazon.  To speed up the process and better maintain data originality I am trying to create a workbook that automates the process.  The goal is to be able to enter/copy an individual or list of unique SKU numbers.  I have created formulas that then interpret the SKU pattern and pull out vital product information.  My problem is that I then need to drag the fill handle to begin calculating that information.  Is there any way in Excel that I can auto-populate cells in each SKU row?  The list of SKU's is always changing from 1 SKU to thousands.  I could fill the formula down to the end of each column, however, this drastically slows down my processing.  I need a fast and dynamic way to autofill my entire spreadsheet based on a SKU or SKU's.

Comment: Show some examples of what you mean and some code of yours trying at that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your template into an Excel Table using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcut. These have calculated columns that autofill formulas, and the tables themselves auto expand to accommodate new data.